# how do you decode gtfs protobufs in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, gtfs, protocol-buffers

I am trying to use https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js to parse triments gtfs data.

Here is the code I have so far, it parses the .proto file correctly and creates the builder and has all the expected properties and methods, it throws an error when I try to decode any data with it.

```
Error: Data must be corrupt: Buffer overrun
```

the proto file is from https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/gtfs-realtime-proto

```
var ProtoBuf = require('protobufjs')
  , request = require('request')

var transit = ProtoBuf.protoFromFile('gtfs-realtime.proto').build('transit_realtime')

request('http://developer.trimet.org/ws/V1/FeedSpecAlerts/?appID=618F30BB3062F39AF24AED9EC', parse)

function parse(err, res, body) {
  try {
    console.log(transit.FeedMessage.decode(res.body))
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

Thanks to Brian Ferris I able to parse the first part of the header `gtfs_realtime_version: "1"` but the parser fails on the next component (the time stamp uint64)

Thanks to

Comment: I am using res.body because it is a buffer, and the body that is passed in is a string

Comment: have you figured out this issue yet? I am getting exactly the same problem looking at the MTA subway gtfs-r feed.

Comment: nope sorry, I gave up, at the time my conclusion was that the js parsers were not up to spec, but maybe some of them have been updated since

Answer (score 4):

I kept finding your question when searching for the same issue you were having and hopefully I can help someone else. After scouring the internet for a lot longer than I should have, I've come up with something that works. I didn't quite understand the data until I had a working feed decoded.

It largely appears that this has to do with how the data is being read. I'm not a NodeJS person so I don't know why, but it's dependent on how the data is read with `http` rather than `request` for decoding. I couldn't get the same method to work with `request` for the data.

Part of this I found from https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/wiki/How-to-read-binary-data-in-the-browser-or-under-node.js%3F but I didn't quite yet understand how to use `protobufjs`, so I'm putting a working example here for others. Hope it helps.

```
var ProtoBuf = require('protobufjs');
var http = require("http");

// create a protobuf decoder
var transit = ProtoBuf.protoFromFile('gtfs-realtime.proto').build('transit_realtime');
// your protobuf binary feed URL
var feedUrl = "...";    

// HTTP GET the binary feed
http.get(feedUrl, parse);

// process the feed
function parse(res) {
    // gather the data chunks into a list
    var data = [];
    res.on("data", function(chunk) {
        data.push(chunk);
    });
    res.on("end", function() {
        // merge the data to one buffer, since it's in a list
        data = Buffer.concat(data);
        // create a FeedMessage object by decooding the data with the protobuf object
        var msg = transit.FeedMessage.decode(data);
        // do whatever with the object
        console.log(msg);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

From the Google Developers page at [developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/examples/nodejs-sample](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/examples/nodejs-sample).
Google has now made a [Node.js npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gtfs-realtime-bindings) available to make things very easy:

```
npm install gtfs-realtime-bindings
```

Here's Google's code snippet ( [Apache 2.0 License](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) )

```js
var GtfsRealtimeBindings = require('gtfs-realtime-bindings');
var request = require('request');

var requestSettings = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'URL OF YOUR GTFS-REALTIME SOURCE GOES HERE',
  encoding: null
};
request(requestSettings, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var feed = GtfsRealtimeBindings.transit_realtime.FeedMessage.decode(body);
    feed.entity.forEach(function(entity) {
      if (entity.trip_update) {
        console.log(entity.trip_update);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: How can I get this same benefit in my angularjs project? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320162/gtfs-realtime-bindings-in-angularjs?s=1|4.8993

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work (with New York MTA feeds, anyway) by forcing the `request` module to have a null encoding, thus ensuring it returns a buffer instead of a string. Like so:

```
request({
    url: 'http://developer.trimet.org/ws/V1/FeedSpecAlerts/?appID=618F30BB3062F39AF24AED9EC'
    encoding: null
}, parse)
```

Then the parsing appears to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your issue but you can get RT feed in text using url like http://developer.trimet.org/ws/V1/FeedSpecAlerts/appid/618F30BB3062F39AF24AED9EC/text/true

Also have a look at [node-gtfs](https://github.com/brendannee/node-gtfs) module.

Comment: thanks for the text link, I hadn't seen that in the docs. it gives me something to work from, seeing what the output is supposed to be may make it easier for me to debug the issue. The node-gtfs module is pretty cool, but I am mostly working on this because I wanted to see how protobufs could work with node.  I'm not really work towards any particular goal, but if I get things working I'll probably write a simple wrapper around the trimet api and put it up on npm

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a node expert, but the root message type of a GTFS-realtime feed is "FeedMessage":

https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/reference

You seem to be trying to parse the feed as an "Alert" message:

`console.log(transit.Alert.decode(res.body))`

Maybe try changing Alert to FeedMessage and see what happens?

Comment: Thank! that's a step in the right direction.  Unfortunatly I am now getting a new error `Error: Data must be corrupt: Buffer overrun` I'm about to update the question