# gtfs-realtime-bindings in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, gtfs

Reading through the GTFS-Realtime, I came across these code samples, with [Javascript in the list](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/code-samples#javascript_nodejs).

The gtfs-realtime-bindings module happens to read gtfs.zip files properly and interpret them appropriately.

I want to use the package in my angular project. How can I?

Comment: what does your angular project do?

Comment: @vcp Takes a gtfs zip file and outputs the trip updates for use in a web app.

Answer (score 1):

*gtfs-realtime-bindings* is available as node module and you can use nodejs and angularjs in the same project, see i.e. **https://scotch.io/tutorials/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular** <- nice

In this thread is a general way how to include node modules in angular (extract the javascript or **browserify**): [Using node module in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29710239/using-node-module-in-angularjs)

https://angularjs.de/artikel/angularjs-browserify

Comment: Got to use browserify. However, facing issues with decoding a gtfs file. Will open a new question for that.